# Write nested lists in a csv file keeping the exact format

Tags: python, csv, nested-lists

I need to store nested lists in a csv file in the exact python format,
i.e., [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]].

I would like to stick to the csv module, so I wrote the simple code below:

```
import csv

matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

with open ('matrix.txt','w',newline='') as f:
    content=csv.writer(f)
    content.writerow(matrix)
```

The code above stores the following in the file:
"[1, 2, 4]","[2, 3, 5]","[3, 4, 6]"
So, we miss the first and last square brackets and get superfluous quoting on top.

I tried various options with delimiter, quotechar, and quoting options as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), but without success.
If converted to a string, it inserts a comma between every char.

How can I store the exact matrix in its original format (i.e., [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]])?

Comment: Might sound dumb but have you tried purposely turning matrix into a list of list of lists? It would look like this: [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]]
EDIT: Just tested and it works

Comment: Try writerow(repr(matrix)); or str(matrix). The issue in your code is that writerow expects a list of things and tries to turn each element (like [1,2,3]) into a string before writing it to a column in that row, and because there are commas in the string it needs to be quoted. You shouldn’t be worrying about how the CSV looks. If you really want a CSV file, trust CSV module to do the right thing. If you need to get that matrix value back into a Python list of lists, you need another encoding method, like JSON. Pickle might be even better if you have complex types inside each element. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way if you are only looking to store your list in the file and not rely on csv module altogether would be to use simple file reader and writer provided by python.

See if this helps:

```
>>> import ast
>>> 
>>> # Step 1: Storage
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> # Storing matrix as string
>>> with open("test.txt","w+") as fp:
...     fp.write(str(matrix))
... 
33
>>> # Reading the file
>>> with open("test.txt","r") as fp:
...     res=fp.read()
...     print(res)
...     print(type(res))
... 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
<class 'str'>
>>> # Converting string back to list
>>> with open("test.txt","r") as fp:
...     f=fp.read()
...     res=ast.literal_eval(f)
...     print(type(res))
...     print(res)
... 
<class 'list'>
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering beyond the initial question. Your code for converting back to list is also useful. I haven't looked at ast very closely up to now, but this is something I will obviously do today.